# Closed & deleted as opinion based

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

I am asking in regards to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40867472/store-100k-words-in-memory-hash-or-trie):

> I have a mapping of words (`String`) to scores (`Double`) that I need
>   to store in memory, and query efficiently.
>
> I don't care too much what is preprocessing time.
>
> Assuming that the words structure and character distribution are
>   similar to the English language, which data structure is best for a
>   list of size ~100k ?
>
> ### [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) or [Trie](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/trie/PatriciaTrie.html) ?

That was closed as "opinion-based"

The question asks which data structure (trie/hashmap) is a better fit for storing english words and their score.

I do not understand why was this question regarded as opinion based.

The question states a **concrete scenario**, that could be **scientifically evaluated** by implementing the two data structures and benchmarking performance.

Sorry for being pragmatic, but as I understand it,  a question that can be answered by performing a controlled experiment cannot be regarded as "opinion based"

Comment: Can't see the question..... but what is "better fit"? If one has 10X better performance, but will require 1000 more lines of code... do you consider it worth it? Normally the requirements have to be EXTREMELY clear for this type of question (again cannot see the question so this may well all be conjecture)

Comment: You need to provide metrics for comparison if you want to objectively evaluate which is the "Better" option.  You provided no metrics for comparison.

Comment: I can't see the question because it's deleted, however: "Best" and "better" are _subjective keywords._ They are keywords that invite opinions. If you didn't thoroughly qualify what would be "better" then that's likely why it was closed. If you _did_ and it's objectively answerable... Then it could be people were triggered by the word. Again, can't see the question, though.

Comment: The top voted answer just says "this is opinion, test it yourself". Seems pretty clear cut to me.

Comment: If it can be "scientifically evaluated", why doesn't the OP do that evaluation instead of asking a bunch of volunteers to do it?

Comment: @davidism , this is exactly what I'm referring to "test it" and "opinion based" does not seem to fit in the same sentence. When I think of opinion based I think of "python vs ruby" that cannot be verified with a single experiment

Comment: Saying "you can perform a controled experiment, therefore it is not opinion based" is not a good argument. The experiment is necessarily going to abstract away factors that may be important in a real world application. I've had cases where I've had nice "controlled experiments" that told me one solution was faster but when it came to applying it to a specific project I found the solution which was 'bad" in an abstract way was in fact best due to access pattern *in this project*. What to abstract, what to consider important in the controled experiment is a matter of opinion.

Comment: *"could be scientifically evaluated by implementing the two data structures and benchmarking performance"* Well, sure. And you could have done this yourself instead of asking the question. I don't think Stack Overflow should become a code-debugging service. Why do you think it should become a code-benchmarking service? And I couldn't even benchmark this if I *wanted* to, because you didn't include a test case! Quibble all you want about "opinion based"; this does not seem like a good question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @UriGoren *You* can run the experiment because you know the specifics of your situation, the requirements of your situation, and what metrics are appropriate for you.  We *can't* run the experiment, because we have none of that.

Comment: @Servy, the question did state "which solution is more efficient when neglecting initialization", If that wasn't clear enough as a metric, I am more than willing to edit my question

Comment: @CodyGray, the fact that I can spend X hours to come up with a solution does not mean that someone else who already spent those hours cannot help me. Many question can be answered by DIY, just think about future visitors facing this very common dilemma.

Comment: @UriGoren but again... WHAT is efficient? Speed? Memory usage? What if my CPU is crappy but I have access to 200 Gigs of RAM? a solution for my PC wouldn't work if your CPU is amazing but you only have megs of memory to play with.... Again, if "efficient" isn't well defined, then anything goes

Comment: By efficient I mean time spent querying, assuming no space limit, I've edited my question

Comment: Here is my standard advice:  There are so many different variables that it is impracticle to tell you what will be the most efficient.  My advice is to write the code that is natural to you, then profile it.  If you are happy with the performance then stop and move on.  If it is not then look for another approach and profile that.  Without hard numbers it is really hard to tell.

Answer (score 18):

The question asks for "the best fit" without defining any "better" criteria.

Following are not concrete criteria for "better"

- "query efficiently" - means absolutely nothing. Both "item by key" and "all items" are *types of query* as well all variations between.
- "no space limit" is somewhat useful, but moves this more to theoretical question

So the only thing left is opinions of people what they like more.

To make question on-topic make sure to provide concrete criteria. If you consider it performance question make sure to demonstrate what current results are you getting and what goals are.